# ASCII to Raster conversion issues

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, ascii, esri-ascii-raster, error-010328

I am struggling to convert (modified) ASCII files to rasters (examples attached + image of error message). Original ASCII files (which I don't have) were delimited using Excel after which they are tab delimited, as attached. Now it looks like ArcGIS can't convert them back to rasters.

In ArcMap I am using ASCII to raster tool.

In ArcGIS Pro I use Copy Raster.

Even when I replace tabs for spaces (1 space) in these ASCII files, the result is the same.

Also, folder naming, output file extension, everything should be fine, since I followed the advice about ASCII data.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You've got a number of options, including starting over with a new GRIDASCII file from source, and using a different transfer format (e.g. GeoTIFF). Without knowing what you've done in Excel to damage the file, there isn't much we can do. Note that error messages should always be placed in Questions as text, so others can't find this Question.

Comment: It is still ASCII file structure, I only changed spaces to tabs (4 spaces now, looks more organized in structure).

Comment: The code can't read it that way. Therefore, it is not an improvement.

Comment: A google on "esri error 010328" turned up [this Community solution](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/asciitoraster-conversion-error-010328-and-010267/td-p/676989)